# Smallest footprint web server for embedded devices

Tags: javascript, php, html, web

I need to build a super simple web app that has a **very** small footprint: Arm89 processor and 1 GB Ram. The server will be running on a small electronic device that takes a picture of a fingerprint and processes it against a database to determine whether to open a door, so no Tomcat, etc.

The only reason for a web interface is for synching SQLLite databases and HR input.  We're thinking HTML, HTML5, PHP, JavaScript.  All of the answers I have found for this question seem to be dated.

I've seen Python and RubyOnRails both of which I have no experience with but am willing to learn if it seems like a newer, more sophisticated way to accomplish this.

---

**ANSWER:**

> For anyone else looking for a web app that must run in an embedded
>   device with a very small footprint, it turns out that the [BusyBox
>   HTTP Daemon (httpd)](http://wiki.openwrt.org/doc/howto/http.httpd) is the smallest footprint web server out there.

Comment: I am looking for suggestions from someone with more experience than I have.  Some people aren't as smart as you are!

Comment: Hi Lucy. As interesting as the question is, Stack Overflow has a number of guidelines as to what sort of questions may (and may not) be asked. Questions that are very broad or discursive will generally be put on hold, as they don't have a right answer. However, you should get some tips in the comments.

Comment: Apache and PHP is fairly easy on a server. What sort of RAM and CPU will the device have?

Comment: Arm89 processor and 1 GB Ram

Comment: I run LAMP on a machine with half that spec, 512M of RAM `:-)`. You can swap MySQL with SQLite if you want to save a bit more, though (I've found MySQL a bit grumpy with this amount of RAM, but stopping some non-essential services seems to have fixed the odd crash. With 1G you'll be fine).

Comment: @halfer - Never heard of LAMP!  Will have to check on that.

Comment: LAMP = Linux, Apache, MySQL and PHP - just what you've mentioned, but by another name.

Comment: @halfer - I would throw your comment into an answer.  Even though broad questions like this do not have a "right" answer, sometimes "helpful" is good enough.  Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you looked into the built-in web server that comes with PHP?

http://php.net/manual/en/features.commandline.webserver.php

Comment: I was leaning towards your answer, as it does seem to satisfy our needs being that it is not a fully fledged web server.  But then I found out about BusyBox.  I am going to give you the points, because your answer was really very helpful.  Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

As per the comments, this device is not really all that small. Apache and PHP will work OK, with a lightweight operating system like BusyBox, in maybe 256M of RAM. Indeed, [there are sites](http://lowendbox.com/) dedicated to advising people what virtual servers to buy, using as little as 64 or 128M!

With a full 1G of RAM, you'll be fine with Apache and PHP, and you won't really need to tune much either. Some MySQL usage will also be OK, but you can swap to SQLite if you don't have many concurrent users. As long as you are not also wanting to run a windowing manager, you can probably use any Linux distro, and just boot up to console level.

Comment: I've updated my question with a little more information that I probably should have added in the first place.  This is a biometric security device that will process fingerprints to open doors instead of badges.  The web application will execute on one of these devices that is dedicated as a master device.  the web interface is merely to synch the databases to all devices on the building and for human interaction.

Comment: Do I need to add anything in light of that, @Lucy? If you are looking to run window manager as well for the UI you'll have to be fairly conservative with memory usage, but it is possible.

Comment: No, I've received two possible answers and will make my determination who gets the check mark based on my research for our particular need.  Again, thank you for your valuable input!  :-)